# I got error with Yii2 assets, kartik widget

Tags: yii2, assets, kartik-v

I have a project Yii2, we recently change web hosting to new provider. This project transfered to me by another coworker, he using WinSCP to drag codes from old hosting to new one. We running this website nomarlly in few weeks until some view not happens correctly.

We have a page using kartik\select2\Select2 widget. In my localhost its show normally the input
[This is the normal Sellect2 widget in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJKSO.png)

But in server this input disappear
[This is the view on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mLYw.png)
In the console it shows multiple errors with message like this:
GET domain../web/assets/5daec188/css/A.bootstrap-dialog-bs4.css.pagespeed.cf.wXboo9MDkr.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I got errors with kartik GridView::FILTER_SELECT2 as well. I think they are more but I not able to discover all of them yet.

How can I fix this error? I want to fix this without remove all the kartik widget. Thank you all